# How to go to a dynamic route using nuxt "to" directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

This works:

```html
<tr
   v-for="item in favourites.slice(0, 5)"
   :key="item.id"
   @click="$router.push('/items/' + item.id)"
>
```

But I want to write something like this because I think it looks cleaner:

```html
<tr
   v-for="item in favourites.slice(0, 5)"
   :key="item.id"
   nuxt
   :to="`/items/${item.id}`"
>
```

I think it doesn't work because Nuxt just looks for "to" and doesn't understand the ":" modifier.
Is there any way to achieve dynamic values in the "to" tag or do I just have to stick to first example, which is working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NuxtLink](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtlink-component).

```html
<NuxtLink
   v-for="item in favourites.slice(0, 5)"
   :key="item.id"
   tag="tr"
   :to="`/items/${item.id}`"
>
```

Comment: I just figured out that my problem isn't the ":to" but rather that my div is a <tr> where even a static to="/item/1" doesn't work because it doesn't have a onClick listener I guess?